# How can I display the field in the tab that was active on save?

Tags: 8, theming, entities, javascript, paragraphs

I'm using Drupal 8 paragraphs. I have a banner_header paragraph that contains three fields,

field_active_callout_tab (boolean)

field_banner_header_single (entity reference revision: paragraph)

field_banner_header_multi (entity reference revision: paragraph)

two of which are displayed in tabs like so:

[image: paragraph fields set to display in tabs]

Here is how the banner_header paragraph shows up on the content type edit form:

[image: single link callout option]

[image: multi link callout option]

When I save the content, I want the page to render with the paragraph from the tab that was active on save.

What I've done so far:

I added classes to the tabs which you can see in the image of the form display: .single-link and .multi-link.  I was told that I also needed to create a boolean field to manage the display behavior, which I did with field_active_callout_tab. The way that was suggested this to work is, the bool will change depending on which tab is selected, and then I can use the bool value to determine which field is to be displayed in the twig template. The default class for this boolean seems to be '.option'.

I created a custom js file to check the status of the tab:

```
(function($, Drupal) {

/* Add span to wysiwyg button classes for alignment
------------------------------------ */
Drupal.behaviors.calloutControl = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
            $('.single-link').click(function () {
                  $('.option').prop('checked', true);
            });
            $('.multi-link').click(function () {
                  $('.option').prop('checked', false);
            });
      }
};

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

And here is the banner_header template:

```
<div class="callout-options">
     {% if content.option == true %}
          {{ content.field_banner_header_single }}
     {% else %}
          {{ content.field_banner_header_multi }}
     {% endif %}
</div>
```

The bool does *not* change depending on the tab selection. It appears to not be impacted at all. The page will *only* render with the multi link paragraph, despite single link setting tab being open on save.

1. Is the bool necessary? If so, what am I missing?
2. If the bool is not necessary, what should I do next?

How can I get the paragraph field in the tab that was active on save, to render on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things that immediatly come to my eye:

1) If you want to check the value of a field, don't use the render array `{% content.field_whatever %}`, because this returns HTML markup and not the value of the field. Most fields types can be checked with something like `{% entity_type.field_name.0.value %}`, in your case `{% paragraph.option.0.value %}`.

2) CSS class names and Twig variable names are completly different things. Are you sure the field name (machine name) of your boolean field is `option`? Drupal by default prefixes every field with `field_`, so the name should be something like `field_whatever`. In your twig you should use something like `{% if paragraph.field_whatever.0.value %}`.

3) A selector like `$('.option')` is super-generic and will almost certainly include other elements anywhere on the page. I don't know your theme, but in my admin theme `.option` is not included in the classes of checkbox. Better use something like `$('input[name*="[field_whatever]"]')`

Comment: Option is the default class, the field machine name is field_active_callout_tab. Would you recommend I set a custom class on that field and reference that instead? Also, as for the checkbox, should I see it check and uncheck as I select between the two tabs, or is that value only registered when the page is saved (and would therefore be reflected if I edited the page again?)

Comment: I just guess `.option` will be added by your theme to any option field on the whole page, so I would definitly use a different selector. AFAIK the Field Group module will add the custom class to a wrapping container, so you would need a descendant selector like `$('.my_custom_and_unique_class .option')`. - The JS code will fire on click, so it will work whenever the editor changes the value (but will only be saved to DB when the editor saves the node). But you should also add some code to make sure that the correct tab is pre-selected/initially open when the editor edits an existing node.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is being called multiple times. To avoid that try Change your **JS** as below

```
$(context).find('.single-link').click(function () {
  $(context).find('.option').prop('checked', true);
});
$(context).find('.multi-link').click(function () {
  $(context).find('.option').prop('checked', false);
});
```

**OR**

change the on `click()` event to `hasClass()` the will be classes added to the active tab